# Why did Maharishi Valmiki write Anand Ramayan?

Tags: rama, valmiki, ramayana

I just found out that Anand Ramayan is attributed to Maharishi Valmiki. So I was wondering as to why would he write another Ramayan apart from Valmiki Ramayan?

Comment: In my opinion, Valmiki did not write the Anand Ramayana. It contradicts many stories with the Valmiki Ramayana, including the details of Sita's kidnapping. Also, the first surviving manuscript of the Anand Ramayana, written by hand, dates back to the 15th Century only.

Comment: Very interesting question!